# Latex fragment in terminal

Tags: org-mode, term, preview-latex

I am currently discovering orgmode and as a math student I want to write my math lessons with this beautiful tool. I love the way LaTeX code can be displayed inline in emacs.

I would like to know if there is a way to preview LaTeX in console mode.
It sounds like an adventure but I really prefer to run emacs in console mode, and of course I'm brave !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle of the preview feature is to display images in the buffer ([doc](http://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html#Previewing-LaTeX-fragments)). About images, Elisp [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Images.html#Images) says:

> Emacs is usually able to display images when it is run on a graphical
>   terminal.  Images cannot be displayed in a text terminal, on certain
>   graphical terminals that lack the support for this, or if Emacs is
>   compiled without image support.

So it seems there's currently no way to do what you want.

Comment: Too bad, but I understand.
I will definitely take a look at emacs server.
Thank you and sorry for haven't look more emacs documentation before asking !