# Is it possible to use AUCTeX preview-latex in emacs terminal?

Tags: auctex, terminal-emacs, preview-latex

I was wondering if it is possible to have latex preview working in emacs terminal. This is somehow related to this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18626/latex-fragment-in-terminal). But 3 years have passed and I'm wondering if anything has changed? For instance iterm terminal allows users to display images directly on the terminal through the imgcat command. I'm wondering is there's anything equivalent for emacs terminal + auctex?

Comment: If you look at the documentation mentionned in the linked answer, you'll see that it hasn't changed.  Apparently emacs still can't display images in a text terminal.

Comment: This is very strange since terminals these days like for instance iTerm can display images fine. So what makes this so difficult, is it really emacs related?

Comment: I guess adding this capability to emacs may require some significant work. Do you know other terminal emulators that can do that? I understand that iTerm is for OSX only.

Comment: I presume something like [this](https://hyper.is/) which is build on electron will not have any issues displaying images. Terminology for linux suppose can do that as well. See discussion here [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/unix/comments/28ab6f/why_dont_modern_terminal_emulators_have_graphics/), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187267/terminal-with-image-support), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97542/how-do-i-make-my-terminal-display-graphical-pictures)